# error in git push over smart http?

Tags: git, apache, http

i have set up a git server using smart-http and i could achieve read access to do clone or pull from the repository, but i am unable to achieve write access to push the changes, so when i give git push origin master, i am getting the error as,

```
    error: Cannot access URL http://username:password@localhost/, return code 22
    fatal: git-http-push failed
```

I have my httpd.conf file as,

```
   ServerName localhost

   SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/nitin/nitinhtml
   SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
   SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
   ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/

   <LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Git Access"
   Require group committers

   </LocationMatch>
```

and I have the sites-enabled/mysite file configured as,

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName gitserver1234
    ServerAlias www.gitserver1234.com
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/nitin/nitinhtml
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
    ScriptAlias /git /var/www/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/

    <Location /nitin>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Private Git Access"
      AuthUserFile "/etc/git-auth-file"
      Required valid-user
    </Location>

    DocumentRoot /home/nitin/nitinhtml
    <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/nitin/nitinhtml>
            Options EXecCGI Indexes
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
              </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
      # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
 </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone point out the mistake in these files ? or is there any other way to configure them ?

Comment: I define a separate virtualhost for /git (I called it /hgit) for and gitweb (/git in my config): https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L147-L184